# scrlttr2: How can I remove the white space between "address" and "Subject:" line?

Tags: spacing, koma-script, letters

How may I remove excessive white space at the top, between my address in top-left, and the Subject: line?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\KOMAoptions{fromalign=left, fromlogo=false, addrfield=false, backaddress=false, subject=titled}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name blah}
\setkomavar{signature}{blah blah}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{blah blah\\blah blah}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{blah@blah}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{123456789}
\setkomavar{subject}{Reference: blah blah}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{asde\\werd\\wesd}
\opening{Dear Adam,}
blah blah
\closing{Yours Sincerely\\ \mbox{}}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

You could adjust the pseudo-length `refvpos` to make the space before the subject line smaller. `refvpos` determines the vertical distance of the reference fields line from the top paper edge.

For example:

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{5cm}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Stefan's answer: While you are not using the address field you may use the position of the address field to set up the position of the reference line or date:

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\makeatletter
```

And if

```
\KOMAoptions{fromalign=left, fromlogo=false, addrfield=false, backaddress=false, subject=titled}
```

and the changed position of the reference line or date should be the default of most of your letter, simply put it into a personal *letter class option* file:

```
\ProvidesFile{Farrukh.lco}[2011/11/22]
\KOMAoptions{fromalign=left, fromlogo=false, addrfield=false, backaddress=false, subject=titled}
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
```

You may also add your settings of `fromname` etc. to this file. After this, you may use option `Farrukh` while loading `scrlttr2`, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[Farrukh]{scrlttr2}
```

to use this saved settings.

Some people even want the date and the opening at the same vertical position. To do so, add

```
\@setplength{refaftervskip}{-\baselineskip}% or even more negative space
```

to the suggested code above.